# Postgres/Postgis doesn't work after update

Tags: postgis-2.0, update

I work on OpenSUSE 12.1 and after today's upgrade (2012 NOV 14) Postgres and Postgis doesn't work. If I login to Postgres server by PgAdmin, get the message: *translated from polish*
"ERROR: can't acces to file "$libdir/postgis-2.0".Theres no file or directory"

When I want create spatial extension by typing 
"  psql -d sulo1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"  " than I get :
`cannot open control extension "/usr/share/postgresql91/extension/postgis.control": no file and folder`

Have to configure my postgis for a new upgrades?

Comment: Where did you get the update files for PostGIS from?

Comment: There was automatic updates, from official repository. Update was for Postgis, Posgres, GDAL, QGIS and other. 
After update I have:
-postgis2 2.0.1-2.3
-postgresql client 9.1.5+9.1.3.14.1
-postgresql91 9.1.6-9.1

Comment: source of updates:  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_12.1/

Comment: I've tested that on 2 servers with OpenSUSE. Each one after automatic updates has that problem.

Comment: Maybe it's looking at the wrong path. On my Ubuntu system, the path is /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control. A simple symlink at /usr/share/postgresql91/ might work as a temporary fix.

Comment: What did you have before the update?

Comment: I had the same pathes, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved by me, but I am not glad with how I did it. 
OpenSUSE provided a patch to Postgres 9.1.7 which assumes different directory structure on the disk: `/ usr/share/postgresql91 /` and not as before `/ usr / share / postgresql /` This is the official upgrade OpenSSUSE number 775.
However, Postgis (at now - 2012 NOV 18) is not prepared for this new patch and install it's $ libdir/Postgis-2.0 to the old catalogs structure.
Uninstalling latest version of  Posgres 9.1.6 and reinstall the PostGIS database was take effect, and it works.
Below is a screenshot of how it looks like in my Yast.

[image: installed packages]

above are installed packages, below uninstalled packages

[image: uninstalled packages]

Thanks for help everyone, especially for symlinks - that was very important for the INVESTIGATION :-)